# Getting 404 Not Found Trying to Login User

Tags: spring-lemon

I am able to signup and verify a user using Google's Advanced Rest Client.  However, when I try to login the user, I get this response:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1471401958802
    "status": 404
    "error": "Not Found"
    "message": "No message available"
    "path": "/api/core/login"
}
```

I am passing the `content-type` and `X-Xsrf-Token` header fields with the following json in the POST request:

```
{
    "email": "user1@example.com",
    "password": "user1!",
    "rememberMe": "false"
}
```

What is the issue?

Comment: Here is the API documentation for login: https://naturalprogrammer.gitbooks.io/spring-lemon-getting-started/content/api/log_in.html . Are you trying /api/core/login instead?

Comment: Yes, I was using the wrong mapping.  Now I'm getting "status": 401
"error": "Unauthorized"
"message": "Authentication Failed: Bad credentials"
"path": "/login".  I can't even login the admin that was created initially.  I know I am using the correct credentials, since I am getting them right out of the application.properties file.  Anyway, I give up.

Comment: No clues. Maybe the demo projects can get you some clues. You'll find the links to the demo projects (both backend and an angular 1 frontend) in the GitHub project home page. The demo backend projects also have test cases that might be of help.